# Windows Explorer won't load correctly, appears to incessantly scan "This PC" and never completes

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I'm trying to use Windows Explorer. Whenever I launch the application, it appears to attempt to load This PC, but this runs indefinitely and never completes. This is the window I see:

[image]

I've tried restarting the computer but it doesn't help.

What can I check to see if something is wrong or broken? How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a bad drive my friend.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-8) or [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?